# parse xml from html POST

Tags: javascript, html, xml, post

if it possible tell if an Iframe content has changed after the page has loaded?

```
$('iframe').on('load' function () {
alert('iframe loaded')
})
```

will only alert once th page has loaded.

```
$('iframe').on('change' function () {
alert('iframe changed')
})
```

is not called if addition content is added to the iframe

Comment: THIS IS NOT A CROSS DOMIAN IFRAME ISSUE!!! I am just trying to read the contents of the Iframe on my page which is on my server. I post and get a response. I put the response in an iframe on a page on MY server. I have full access to the page, the iframe, the server, I just do not know how to get the xml or how to parse it.

Comment: Then, please clarify that in your question by editing it. Your question should contain all the details for us to be able to identify the issue. It will then be reopened. Although, I'm pretty sure this is still a duplicate. Look up "accessing iframe contentWindow".

Comment: Thanks blex, I looked at a number of these posts and their solutions. The first part is understanding when/if the content has been placed in the iframe. The second part is reading the data to do something with it. Thanks for your help.